# Static library code uses wrong address for extern struct residing in application code

Tags: c, embedded, rtos

really strange error on my side. I am programming a firmware for a Cortex-M4f running Nucleus RTOS. For my application I have some prebuilt static libraries (e.g. libexternal.a) which expect an global struct which must be provided by the application (declared extern inside the static library).

From within my application code I can access the struct just fine, but from within the code of the static library I always get an HardFault interrupt.

Through debugging I found that the processor tries to access the struct on the wrong address. Here is some example pseudo-code:

**appconfig.c**

```
struct AppConfiguration g_appconfig = {

/* initialize everything statically */
};
```

**main.c**

```
include <staticlib.h>

void main(){
  g_appconfig.somemember = 1 /* this works */

  staticlib_lib_init();
}
```

Everything below is part of the static library and prebuilt befor compiling the application.

**appconfig.h**

```
struct AppConfiguration{
  uint32_t somemember;
};
```

**staticlib.h**

```
#include "appconfig.h"
extern struct AppConfiguration g_appconfig;

void static_lib_init();
```

**staticlib.c**

```
#include "staticlib.h"

void static_lib_init(){

  g_appconfig.somemember = 1 /* causes a HardFault */
}
```

The static library is compiled with flags:

```
-ffunction-sections
-fdata-sections
-fno-builtin-memcpy
-DARM_MATH_CM4=1
-mthumb
-mcpu=cortex-m4
-mfloat-abi=soft
-fPIC
-Wno-unused-but-set-variable
```

and the application with flags:

```
-ffunction-sections
-fdata-sections
-fno-builtin-memcpy
-mthumb
-mcpu=cortex-m4
-g
-mfloat-abi=soft
```

Through debugging I discovered that the static library tries to access g_appconfig at the wrong Memory address. E.g.

g_appconfig starts at address 0x2000061c and static_lib_init() tries to access it at address 0xff7f4342. My SRAM is 320k large starting at 0x2000000 and my ROM is 2MB large starting at 0x8000000. So it makes no sense to access memory at 0xff...... (propably some hardware register or anything else).

Dissassembly of static_lib_init() looks like following:

```
00000000 <static_lib_init>:
   0:   b5f0        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   2:   b08f        sub sp, #60 ; 0x3c
   4:   af06        add r7, sp, #24
   6:   6178        str r0, [r7, #20]
   8:   6139        str r1, [r7, #16]
   a:   60fa        str r2, [r7, #12]
   c:   60bb        str r3, [r7, #8]
   e:   4cf9        ldr r4, [pc, #996]  ; (3f4 <static_lib_init+0x3f4>)
  10:   447c        add r4, pc
  12:   4bf9        ldr r3, [pc, #996]  ; (3f8 <static_lib_init+0x3f8>)
  14:   58e3        ldr r3, [r4, r3]
  16:   461a        mov r2, r3
  18:   2301        movs    r3, #1
  1a:   f8c2 30d0   str.w   r3, [r2, #208]  ; 0xd0
```

`r2` should contain the starting address of `g_appconfig` (#208 is the offset of the element I want to access in my realworld code), but while debugging contains 0xff7f4342.

Any idea how this could happen? Shouldn't the linker replace the address of g_appconfig in the resulting static library while linking?

Comment: I would advocate avoidance of the issue altogether and pass a pointer to the structure at runtime into the library.  Also https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/ in any case.

Comment: changing the library source code is not a viable solution. it's a huge 3rd party library and this is a fundamental part of the architecture. So changing this would require to change the whole library.

Comment: I appreciate that may be the case.  Just pointing out the poor design choices.  If I thought it were a solution I'd have posted an answer.  Why do you need PIC on an M4 MCU? I assume you are not dynamically loading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you a sure-bet smoking gun answer without being able to test it myself, but my guess is the problem is that you're building your library with `-fPIC`, but your main application is not.

Keep in mind that when you ask the compiler to generate position independent code, you're also asking it to generate position independent data. In your case the global variable `g_appconfig` is going to be at a fixed location determined by the linker.

Try taking out the `-fPIC` option on your library build. Since you're only linking statically you don't really need it, and it's more likely to hurt your performance than help.

Comment: You are my personal hero for today. Removing `-fPIC` solved this issue! But I still do not fully understand why this caused this problem.

Comment: @A.K. Glad I could help! These little comment boxes don't leave a lot of room for technical discussion but the reason is fairly simple: when you use `-fPIC` in your library, all global variables are looked up via the global offset table, which is expected to be set up by a dynamic run time. In a statically linked executable, there is no meaningful global offset table, so your library code is essentially looking up a random address for the global.